# How to redirect from www.domain.com to domain.com?

Tags: apache

I am using the following code in my `httpd.conf` for redirections:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But, it ends up redirecting to `www.domain.com/domain.com//domain.com//domain.com`

I want all the following URLs to redirect to domain.com:

```
http://domain.com
http://www.domain.com
www.domain.com
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do it.  The problem is that it looks pretty much like what you already have.  When you type `http://domain.com` in your browser, does it work?  Or does it redirect to somewhere else?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: It works when I go to http://domain.com, but it does not work when I go to http://www.domain.com or www.domain.com

Comment: When you to go domain.com it shows your website just fine, but if you go to www.domain.com it does the weird broken URL thing.  Did I correctly interpret what you said?

Comment: Actually, this only happens in Chrome. In Firefox, www.domain.com goes to domain.com//. How come there is an extra slash at the end of the URL?

Comment: Ah!  The extra slash comes from the (.*) match.  It matches the opening slash.  I've edited my answer above to compensate.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to change anything. I still get the double slash after www.domain.com -> domain.com//. I restarted my Apache server, so it should reflect the changes I made. And do you know why I get different results in browsers?

Comment: Can you provide the domain that you are doing this on so I can see the HTTP headers that are being sent/received?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11448/discussion-between-egidra-and-dusty-wilson)

Comment: Everything seems to be working well from my point of view in multiple browsers, including Chrome, Firefox, and wget. It's possible that browser caching is causing your end to not see your recent updates to your Apache config. Or your nginx reverse proxy could have been serving old info with regard to the redirect.  Please be sure to clear your browser cache to see if that helps.

Comment: You HAVE TO add "/" before "$1", otherwise, if you have other rules that redirects from root "/" to "/subfolder/", the redirected URL will become "http://domain.comsubfolder/". For example in my case, I redirect "http://liveditor.com" to http://liveditor.com/text-editor/"

Answer (score 1):

http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml suggests

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect ANY non-www request to https and www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.\.domain\.com)?$

RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect ANY HTTP request to https and www
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443

RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

for SSL Virtual host use the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yourdomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Full Example below:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin youname@yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/yourdomain"
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    ServerAlias  www.yourdomain.com *.yourdomain.com
    ErrorLog "logs/yourdomain-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/yourdomain-access_log" common
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
    <Directory "/var/www/html/yourdomain">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain/chain.pem
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yourdomain\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```